# Headline with invisible character is getting cut off

Tags: html

I have a html which have some text in h1 tag say

```
<h1>Analyzing the Relationship between the Vertex and y-Intercept of a Quadratic Function</h1>
```

I am not sure if you can see when I post here, there is a hidden character before **y-Intercept**. The problem I am facing is when I open that html kept in my local machine using my local browser I see the whole text, but when I open that same page kept on some server using my local browser, whole text after that hidden character has been cut off. So I only see "Analyzing the Relationship between the Vertex and".

I have no idea why is it happening!! If anyone can just point me in the direction in which I should look for, that would be a great help. Or may be give me the solution itself.

EDIT:
jsfiddle link to see that hidden characted
http://jsfiddle.net/P4cfG/

And screenshots of my local html response with no cut off and of my server response with cut off text respectively
[image: With full text]

[image: With cut off text]

Comment: What do you mean a 'hidden character'? What did you type?

Comment: Check CSS rules. There's maybe a strange rule that specify a width for your h1 and hide text on overflow. Check also the container in his area. There's maybe some div with a superior Z-Index. Give us more details, like a link to your site of a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem please (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This might be related to encoding of page. Try setting it to UTF-8. I guess it can be done by adding ``<meta charset="UTF-8">`` in ``HEAD`` tag

Comment: It is vague, fornessa more details such as CSS and the rest of the HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a `Vertical tab` there anyways?

Comment: @Liath... I have added a jsfiddle link. Please check it out.

Comment: @NicolasHenrard...CSS rules and html are exactly same on both my local machine and my other server. So It cannot be that CSS or the html code is the reason.

Comment: @Yogesh.. I have already added that in my page. And even if I didn't, there is no point acting it different on different machines. As code is same on both.

Comment: Cant you just remove the character?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering the question, but here is the character as I see it in my editor. After some Google, it seems to be a `Vertical Tab` used for faster printing or something along those lines.

Can you not just remove it?

[image]

Comment: I can surely remove it but I am trying to find out the reason for it to act weird on other machine. The reason being my db is edited my some other people and they might repeat this again as they just copy paste text from word or something. If I know the reason I might be able to find a solution so that any invisible character like this don't mess up my page on my server. Is there a way to show that character in my html so that when editors see it, they remove it by themselves?
Also can you tell me what editor you used?

Comment: Ahh sure! Always good to find a solution on how to handle these things in the future. I'll continue digging :) The editor above is `Sublime text 2` Its great for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to tell everyone how I solved.

As my project is in django. I just made a templatetag to filter those kind of special characters. I am sure you can do it for other frameworks too.

```
@register.filter
def replace_non_printable_characters(string):
    control_chars = ''.join(map(unichr, range(0, 32) + range(127, 160)))
    control_char_re = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))
    return control_char_re.sub('', string)
```